# I need to know why this code is not working

Tags: html, web, frontend, jsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP3zQ.png)
I'd like to make one button with orange colour and String "HELLO I'm title" by JSX but it's not working.
and I don't even know what is the occasions of the error.

so my code is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const root = document.getElementById("root");
    const Title = (
      <h3 id="title" onMouseEnter={() => console.log("mouse enter")}>
        Hello I'm a title
      </h3>
    );
    const Button = (
      <Button
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "tomato", //you can even change colour!
        }}
        onClick={() => console.log("I'm clicked")}
      >
        Click me
      </Button>
    );
    const container = React.createElement("div", null, [Title, Button]);
    ReactDOM.render(container, root);
  </script>
</html>
```

there are so many error code so I can't consider all of that
please help me

this is the result what I want to make

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb9vA.png)

Comment: Orange React button [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdce7zx6/)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a component called `Button (capitalized)` and inside this `Button`, you're using the same component called `Button` like a recursive approach. I think the error is caused by a typo.

Try to use a component like `Button` and inside this button, use native html `button (lowercase)`